# GPS tracking data string format for GRTQ device

Tags: gps, php

I get GPS data from tcp (php socket), but for some devices (GRTQ) I will get an unreadable string.

First devices sends:

```
*HQ,XXXXXX,41,4#V1,time,A,**Lat**,N/S,**Lng**,W/E,000.00,000,date,FFFFFBFF,432,35,32448,334
```

then sends:

```
*HQ,XXXXXX,V9,time,A,**Lat**,N/S,**Lng**,W/E,000.10,000,date,,Caller ID,FFFFFBFF#
```

then sends:

```
$A  grQ05Ah@‘)���ÿÿûÿÿ����°#~À‚¡U
```

What's the meaning of this last string?

The model of the device is GRTQ.

Comment: I can find no reference to a device model of GRTQ. The string appears to be binary data. I suspect without knowing the device or manufacturer it won't be possible to determine what that string represents.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the received unreadable data to hexadecimal string.
You will get this
24 41 20 20 67 72 51 30 35 41 68 40 2018 29 fffd fffd fffd ff ff fb ff ff fffd fffd fffd fffd b0 23 7e c0 201a a1 55

Then you can split it and parse it like this.
First 2 digital(24),  stand for standard mode
next 10 digital,  is device'ID (41 20 20 67 72)
6 digital, is time 
6 digital, is data
8 digital, is latitude
2 digital, battery like this 06= 100% 05=80% 04=60% 03=40% 02=20% 01=10%
10 digital is  longitude

next byte C is  16 hexadecimal, 0C,  convert it into binary data, 1100 (4 bit)

Bit 3:    if is 1= East longitude  if is 0= West  longitude
Bit 2:      if is 1= North latitude,  if is 0= South latitude
Bit1:      if  is 1= A( GPS position valid) if is 0= V( gps position invalid)
Bit 0: discard

000215: 6 digits, 000 is speed (knot  1 knot =1.852 km/h )  , 215 is direction in degrees.

FFFFF9FF:vehicle_status
2 bytes :back-up data 
2bytes  :gsm_signal
0D : （convert to decimal=13  13 means the number of satellite gps_signal) 000000034 :   mileage
4bytes: mobile country code (China)
00: mnc
0000: lac
0000: cell_id
00: record number

Comment: I had the same problem here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375499/data-from-gps-sometimes-changed-to-unreadable-format